# How to decide , on number of config servers and mongos servers while sharding an existing database which is growing continuously in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

If I  have a huge mongo db database which has around 4000 collections which is growing seamlessly , If I decide to implement sharding . How to decide on number of config servers and mongos servers and also shard servers . I am now very much familiar with sharding now  , I just need suggestions to decide on number of servers .

Thanks in advance for any suggestions provided

Comment: number of config servers is easy. three.  no other possibility exists.

Comment: You should have a minimum of three shard servers (one primary and two secondary) per shard.  The number of shards you need depends on the total amount of data you have, the number of queries per second that your cluster has to handle, and the number of writes per second your cluster has to handle.

Comment: The number of mongos's that you need depends on the number of simultaneous incoming connections.  While the number of incoming connections that an single 'mongos' process can handle will vary based on workload, 300 connections per 'mongos' is a good planning number.

Comment: Thank you william and Asya for valuable information .  If i have 3 mongos servers , will the connections automatically get split-ed like you said 300 connections per mongos